# Check quotes in string which is number followed by comma

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

i am creating plsql function which has string as input example
`('1234,4565,1212,7658') is right
('1234,
4565,1212,7658') is not right as return 
('12345,
4565,121552,7658')`
 is not right more than 4 char

i want to ensure user using function enters only 2 quotes
have only 4 char as number and separated by comma 
how do i raise exception if any of above is violated.

i have tried `REGEXP_LIKE(Column ,'^['][0-9]{d},[']$')`  but its not working

i have tried `REGEXP_LIKE(Column ,'^['][0-9]{d},[']$')`  but its not working

`REGEXP_LIKE(Column ,'^['][0-9]{d},[']$')`  but its not working

**expected:**

`('1234, 4565,1212,7658')`

**not expected**

```
('1234, 
4565,1212,7658')

('123456, 
45654,1212,7658')
```

Comment: It's not clear to me if strings are like `'1234,5678'` or `1234,5678`; do you need to check if a given string is only made by a list of comma separated 4-digits numbers, right?

Comment: hi – Aleksej, Strings should be like '1234,5678'. i need to also make sure its enclosed in single quotes and made by a list of comma separated 4-digits numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one

```
WITH tab AS(
  SELECT '''1234,4565,1212,7658''' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '''1234,4565,4565,1212,7658''' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '''1234m,4565,1212,7658' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '''1234,45655,1212,7658' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '''1234,456,1212,7658''' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '''1234,4565,1212'',7658''' AS str FROM dual       
)
SELECT * FROM tab t
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t.str ,'^['']([[:digit:]]{4},)+([[:digit:]]{4})['']$')
```

Result:

```
str
------
'1234,4565,1212,7658'
'1234,4565,4565,1212,7658'
```

Comment: how do i ensure that this is not entered ..    ('1234, carriage return
4565,1212,7658')

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE(t.str ,'^['']([[:alnum:]]{4},)+([[:alnum:]]{4})['']$') I would assume for alphanumeric also this should work if we modify it to alnum

Comment: @user1742716 yes

Comment: I noticed alnum also selects numbers, how can i modify above regular expression to select only characters and charac+numb but exclude numeric eg 'avds' and '12sf' is ok but '1234' is not

Comment: @user1742716 Please do not expand your answers by comments. If you have another question, then you should create a new question. please also describe all possible configurations. is it only 4 digits on 2 digits + 2 chars or so 1 digit + 3 chars and so on